# How to include syscalls.c from a separate library file?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, system-calls

My code includes indirect calls to functions like `_write()` and `_sbrk()`. Within the project I have a file called `syscalls.c` that defines my custom implementations of these functions, and the compiler/linker finds this file, and links to the functions correctly when I run make. The compile line make creates looks something like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -nostartfiles -mcpu=arm7tdmi -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--cref  -L../hardware_drivers/lib -L../framework/lib -T../linker-script.lds -Wl,-Map,./build/bin/Mapfile.map -o build/bin/Elffile.elf ./build/obj/Main.o ./build/obj/SomeCode.o ./build/obj/syscalls.o -Wl,--start-group -lhardware_drivers -lframework -Wl,--end-group
```

This works perfectly. However, I want to move syscalls.c to the hardware_drivers project that I have, so they should be included in the libharware_drivers.a file that gets created when I compile hardware_drivers, and included by the gcc line above. Moving the file and recompiling all my projects does include my syscalls.c in the .a file (shown using `arm-none-eabi-ar`). However, when it comes to compile my top level project, I get this error:

```
../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x1c): undefined reference to `_fstat'
```

I'm using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` v4.8 from code sourcery and I'm compiling it for a AT91SAM7A1 chip, if that has any relevance.

Is there something special you need to do to point the linker to syscalls when it's in a separate library file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use,

1. `-nostartfiles`
2. You create a file with `_fstat` in *libhardware_drivers.a*
3. You use some code with `_fstat_r` calling ../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o)

Here is the error message,

> ../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function '_fstat_r':
>   fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x1c): undefined reference to '_fstat'

You can try to find the code which uses the `_fstat_r` from a map file or with `-nodefaultlibs` or `-nostdlibs`.  The issue is that libraries are resolved in a first to last order.  You have an implicit `-lc` at the end of your linker list.  If you intend to use the the 'C' library, then you must alter your linker command to position  *libhardware_drivers.a* later in the link.

For example,

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -nostartfiles -mcpu=arm7tdmi -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--cref\
 -L../hardware_drivers/lib -L../framework/lib -T../linker-script.lds \
 -Wl,-Map,./build/bin/Mapfile.map -o build/bin/Elffile.elf ./build/obj/Main.o\
 ./build/obj/SomeCode.o ./build/obj/syscalls.o \
 -Wl,--start-group -lc -lhardware_drivers -lframework -Wl,--end-group
```

Here, a **-lc** is placed before `-lhardware_drivers`.  This will let the linker resolve the *lib_a-fstatr.o* reference to `_fstat` in your *syscall.o*.  Another way is to force some synthetic reference earlier in another object file (like *Main.o*).  A macro can force the link,

```
#define FORCE_LINK(x) void* __ ## x ## _force_link =(void*)&x
FORCE_LINK(fstat);
```

Most likely you have circular references in your static libraries.  Ie, *hardware_drivers* refers to *framework* refers to *libc* (and *libc* refers back to *hardware_drivers* to make things work).  Methods to overcome this are to list the libraries multiple times on the command line or restructure your code which is probably better long term.

The restructure is as simple as a separate *libsyscall.a*, which is listed after `-lc`.